# Creating XA DataSource to DB2 on JBoss

Tags: db2, datasource, jboss5.x

I trying to configure an XA DB2 DataSource, `xa-datasource` (based on http://community.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpADB2Datasource) using `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource` class (`local-tx-datasource` works using the `com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver`). The target server is DB2 Connect V9.7

Actual xa-datasource config:

```
<xa-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/DB2ServerDS</jndi-name>
    <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
    <track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx> 
    <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <xa-datasource-property name="URL">jdbc:db2://db2server:50000/FINDB</xa-datasource-property>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.DB2ExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DriverType">4</xa-datasource-property>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT * FROM ACC.SETTINGS 1=2</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <user-name>findbuser</user-name>
    <password>findbuser</password>
    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>10000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <type-mapping>DB2</type-mapping>
    <no-tx-separate-pools/>
</xa-datasource>
```

and the following jar in the JBoss node lib directory:

```
db2umplugin.jar         
db2policy.jar           
db2dbgm.jar             
db2jcc_license_cu.jar   
db2jcc.jar              
db2jcc4.jar             
db2java.zip             
db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
```

but i'm getting the error:

```
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: [jcc][10389][12245][3.57.82] Failure in loading native library db2jcct2, java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no db2jcct2 in java.library.path:  ERRORCODE=-4472, SQLSTATE=null
```

The driver for XA is trying to use native libraries, despite the fact that i'm using a JDBC Type 4 driver.

Why is the driver trying to use native libraries? Is there anything i need to add to my config?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is not to use the URL to specify the connection settings.

```
<xa-datasource>
    <jndi-name>jdbc/DB2ServerDS</jndi-name>
    <use-java-context>false</use-java-context>
    <track-connection-by-tx>true</track-connection-by-tx> 
    <xa-datasource-class>com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2XADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
    <exception-sorter-class-name>org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.vendor.DB2ExceptionSorter</exception-sorter-class-name>
    <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">db2server</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">50000</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">FINDB</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DriverType">4</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="User">findbuser</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="Password">findbuser</xa-datasource-property>
    <xa-datasource-property name="DriverType">4</xa-datasource-property>
    <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT * FROM ACC.SETTINGS 1=2</check-valid-connection-sql>
    <user-name>findbuser</user-name>
    <password>findbuser</password>
    <min-pool-size>2</min-pool-size>
    <max-pool-size>10</max-pool-size>
    <blocking-timeout-millis>10000</blocking-timeout-millis>
    <type-mapping>DB2</type-mapping>
    <no-tx-separate-pools/>
</xa-datasource>
```

Credit to http://dev.wavemaker.com/forums/?q=node/3127

The correct JARs are

```
db2jcc_license_cu.jar             
db2jcc4.jar                         
db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar
```

Should you get an error like:

```
org.jboss.resource.JBossResourceException: Could not create connection; - nested throwable: (com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-5042, SQLSTATE=     , SQLERRMC= ;1208;FINDBUSER;FINDB;QDB2; ; ; ;1208; , DRIVER=4.7.85)
```

check http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21405243&myns=swgimgmt&mynp=OCSSEPGG&mync=R for the solution.

I hope this saves others some frustration and time.

Comment: I think license_cu and license_cisuz should not be used both. cu is the free license, cisuz is the commercial one that contains more platforms (one per letter in the postfix) - you want one or the other, not both.